What happens if a barbarian throws a flying creature?
If a Path of the Giant barbarian uses its Mighty Impel feature on a creature with a flying speed to throw it into a chasm, does the creature fall?
Does whether or not the creature was actively flying when it was thrown, and/or if it was flying by magical means, matter? If so, how does it change the answer?
Mighty impel says;

If, at the end of this movement, the thrown creature isn’t on a surface or liquid that can support it, the creature falls, taking damage as normal and landing prone.

I can not find anything in the flying rules that directly states that this wouldn't happen. However, it makes no sense that a creature that can fly would fall just because they were thrown; Especially if they were flying by magical means, such as the fly spell.
Mechanically, Mighty Impel does not reduce the creature's speed to zero or prevent them from moving, and only knocks them prone as a result of landing. Those are the conditions which would Normally cause a flying creature to stop flying and fall, and even then only if they could not hover or were flying magically. However, the flight rules do not strictly say that flying creatures can not fall, or how they interact with effects that indirectly force them to fall.

This would have e been so much simpler if they said "fluid" instead of "liquid" specifically...

"However, it makes no sense that a creature that can fly would fall just because they were thrown" How well do birds fly backwards?  (Hint: They can't, because their wings aren't stable in that direction.)  And you're disregarding the force that goes into the throw too.  However they'd only fall 500ft in one round, so if it's a reasonably deep chasm then they get to recover and fly back out before they hit the ground.

@Graham Most birds do not fly backwards especially well, it's true. Hummingbirds do it quite well, though, and so do insects. Basically all flying creatures also have a recovery distance, when falling, of less than a few feet to right themselves and resume flying unless significantly injured. The effect causes no damage, so I stand by my statement; It makes no sense that a creature that can fly would fall after being thrown.

@Zach "Not especially well" sounds like British understatement, when they literally fall out of the air like a brick! Make it a few tens of feet and you're closer. You may want to watch birds when they're hit by another bird mid-flight and have to recover; or what they do when they hit turbulent air. (I spent years birdwatching with my folks.) And don't forget that we're talking birds with a bodyweight at most a tenth of a human. A sparrow can recover almost instantly; a vulture not so much; and an aarakocra, even less so. Your DM might make house rules, but it's not too far wrong for reality.

@Graham So, for clarity, your stance is that a flying bird would, realistically, fall 'a few tens of feet' and then be able to recover; Under conditions as severe as turbulent air, or being struck by another-larger-bird mid flight. So, surely, based on that statement, you must agree that simply tossing a bird gently enough that it could easily land on its feet-something that happens when the ability 'throws' the bird onto a solid surface-that it would not instantly plummet 500 feet, without being able to resume flight first.

@Zach Well, RAW are what they are, and in this case aren't a good fit for the real world with a small bird.  OTOH your initial position of "it doesn't fall at all" also isn't a good fit for the real world, especially for something the size of an aarakocra which is going to take some time (and distance) to get its wings back working again.  So if you're going to appeal to the DM to make a house rule that's closer to reality than RAW, you're going to be somewhere in between.

@Zach ... Also you may want to be careful what you wish for.  A DM motivated to make this more realistic may also decide that this can cause damage to any winged creature, in the same way that aircraft can be damaged by extreme gusts of wind.  Reality can bite back. :)

@Graham Since you seem to think it's relevant to the question, I will add this context; The situation that sparked this question involved one of my players-as I am the DM-using the ability on an enemy wearing winged boots. At the time, I ruled that the magic item would keep the creature from falling. I am uncertain as to why you think Aarakocra are so relevant to the question, and no, I'm not worried about the DM being petty. I asked this question hoping for context that might help me make a more informed ruling in the future, as the player seemed upset by my decision.

The creature falls unless it can stay aloft.
Like your said in your question it mostly depends on the means of flying the creature have, for example flying spell allows the creature to end its turn in midair and in that case the creature being thrown should remain in the place where the forced movement ends.
That said RAW by reading that ability it should fall.
This ability specifically addresses surface and liquid. Air is a gas, so by reading the ability as is the creature should fall regardless. But then if we take into account RAI then the creature under the effect of the fly spell and similar means of flying should be able to stay in midair at the end of forced movement imposed by this ability.

If you really want to be a That Guy (TM), you might point out that under certain criteria gases might actually be a type of liquid, so the Fly spell is just holding you on a liquid that supports you. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540065

@Pyrotechnical Unfortunately general consensus is that DnD 5e in fact is not an physics simulator :) I just believe that designers didn't thought about that specific scenario as if your character can fly then why are you in range of the barbarian the type of stuff :)

Most definitely isn't a physics simulator, but I always find that factoid interesting.

Like most corner cases, there is more than one way to rule this.  Here are a few ways.
Abilities do what they say they do
The ability says the creature falls.  Flying creatures can fall.  So, splat.
As normal
You could use that phrase to do the heavy lifting, on the other hand.  A creature not supported by a fluid or ground who cannot fly would fall "as normal"; a creature who can fly wouldn't fall unless its speed was reduced to 0.
This is making "fall, taking damage as normal" lifting that "as normal" out of a sub-clause and applying it to the entire clause, which is grammatically really iffy.  But it provides a textual support for what looks like common sense if you want it.
DM's word is final
However, a flying creature falling because it was moved without further explanation seems really strange.  A DM may require a justification - for example, the Barbarian could do a volley-ball style spike to smash the flying creature into the ground, prone: and lacking such a possible geometry (from initial location to fall-flat destination), the fall doesn't occur.
This means that you can spike flying creatures into the ground like you can non-flying creatures - you just gotta arrange for the geometry to work.

My only issue with this explanation is that, strictly speaking, there's nothing anywhere in the rulebook that states flying creatures don't fall when they're not standing on anything. The rules seem to take it as implicit to a creature 'flying' that it does not fall. Neither the rules for flying creatures, nor the rules for falling, actually say that flying creatures Can't fall, except by exclusion. I.e., it doesn't say they 'can't' fall. It only lists conditions under which they do fall.

Just want to add that sending creature to the ground "volley-ball style" using this ability if forced movement wouldn't end above said ground would result in creature standing perfectly fine as if nothing really happened. Overall I think the wording of this ability is poorly made and that question is the proof of that.

@Zach Yes, 5e rules are not written as if they are defining a full system of physics.  "Flying" is assumed to be understood as something that lets you fly, with the rule that at 0 speed "Flying" creatures fall unless they can "Hover".  To deal with how 5e rules are written, you should in general treat 5e rules as covering the typical case, and that the DM should handle atypical cases.  This solves problems with ... pretty much every corner case in 5e, because corner cases are not typical, so the DM should make a reasonable call and move on instead of teasing out what the rules say.

@ArekKubiński Sure - what I am saying is that if you send a target 30' above the ground somewhere, and then they fall 30' to take 3d6 damage, this narratively is similar to the creature being spiked into the ground.  Mechanically the path of travel is different; for flying creatures, I suggest the DM could enforce the strait-line spike be possible, then let the Giant Path barbarian do it to the flying creature.  If the strait-line isn't possible, then I suggest saying "you can't make the flying creature fall by pushing it that way".

@Yakk For clarity; My point was that flying-an ability in 5e D&D-does not do 'what it says it does.' It is an undefined term, which expects the player to intuit how it works, naturally. So your opening claim that 'abilities do what they say they do' holds no water for this system. If your actual answer is "flying in 5e is weird, and this ability is not worded to address how it works, so every DM will have to make a call about the interaction" then that's fine. However, you really should just say that, directly.

@Zach My point is that the giant ability says "the target falls".  It is clear that flying creatures can fall: there are spells that do this, as well as being reduced to 0 speed.  Based on "Abilities do what they say" - this ability causes a creature to fall.  It is a way to read it; not the way I'd play with it, but I'm listing ways to deal with it, not dictating them to you.  There isn't going to be a "one correct way to read the rules", there are going to be a bunch of ways.
